# Switch dropdown menu to button upon selecting an option? Within webpage

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I would like to have a feature on my site that allows me to have a select drop-down and upon selecting an option, it will lock that option into place by replacing the select with a button that holds onto that text.

I am using KnockoutJS, with jQuery.

I suppose I could always just use KnockoutJS's HTML data-bind and just manipulate the select/button in the background using JavaScript but with all the fancy things Knockout can do, thought maybe there was a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Knockout's `visible` binding. In this example the `select` and `button` are toggled based on the value's length, but you could also use a second property to toggle visibility in case you might need to show the `select` again at some point.

**HTML**

```
<select data-bind="value: test, visible: !test().length">
    <option></option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
<button data-bind="text: test, visible: test().length"></button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ViewModel = {
    test: ko.observable('')
};
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bQKt6/2/

Here's a fiddle that uses a secondary property to toggle visibility along with a click handler on the `button` that shows the `select` again: http://jsfiddle.net/LYhDx/1/

Answer (score 1):

Put a [`.change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler on the dropdown, then replace it with jquery with a button. Keep the value of the dropdown by using [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Here's an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Rm69F/